# Alternative for NX server?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, nx, freenx

In past I used to use NX server and client to remotely connect multiple users to one Linux machine. It was a nice gimmick as even though it was the same machine every user had his own desktop environment. All the users could work at the same time on the remote machine. Furthermore, there used to be a nice option where the remote resolution adapted to the client's vnc window. If the client's window was resized, the remote resolution automatically adapted itself (no scaling, but true resolution). Unfortunately, NX is no option today anymore and freeNX does not work properly on newer Ubuntu versions.

Is there any alternative to NX having similar or same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[X2GO](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) is pretty good replacement for NX.

Comment: Please note that it is not compatible with some modern Desktop Environments (see https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat).